# Error installing sidekit using pip on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, sidekit

On this website `http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/sidekit/install.html`
the command was given but its run into following error.

In Ubuntu, both python 2.7 and 3.2 are available but pip command is trying to install in 2.7 env but Sidekit is made for 3.x

---

adit@adit-HP-ProBook-440-G2:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

```
$ pip install sidekit
```

Collecting sidekit

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

*Please give me some suggestions for the above!*

Comment: try sudo pip install sidekit

Comment: No that installs sidekit, but it gives an while importing.

Comment: oh i now read that you use both python 2 and 3 the answer by @Shreyash S Sarnayak is the correct one
http://stackoverflow.com/a/44083767/5306132

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
python3 -m pip install sidekit
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled a little bit with installing `SIDEKIT`, but finally, I was able to install it successfully. My laptop has **Ubuntu 18.04 and python3 is the default python**

And here is what I did:

### Install Dependencies

- You need to install some dependencies as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://projets-lium.univ-lemans.fr/sidekit/install/install.html#dependencies). And these are the dependencies which could be put into a text file called `requirements.txt` and install them all at once using `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
### BEGIN ###
matplotlib>=3.0.0
numpy>=1.15.2
pyparsing>=2.2.2
scipy>=1.1.0
six==1.11.0
h5py>=2.8.0
pandas>=0.23.4
### END ###
```

- Then, You need to install `pytorch` for deep learning model. Follow the PyTorch official website to know how to install it for your system. Mine is Ubuntu, so this is what works for me `pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`
- Next, you need to install `torchvision` by running `pip3 install torchvision`
- Next, install python `TKinter` via `sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk`
- Next, install libsvm, which is a C++ library dedicated to SVM classifiers, by running `sudo apt-get install libsvm-dev`.

### Install SideKit

- Finally, install `SideKit` by running `pip install sidekit`

Now, open the terminal and try to get the version of SideKit and it would return the version if installed correctly... Mine is:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sidekit
>>> sidekit.__version__
'1.3.2'
```